# Automatically split enumeration over multiple pages

Tags: page-breaking

I would need to automatically split a very long enumeration over multiple pages. I've tried several solutions but no one works for me.

Please, could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The standard `enumerate` environment allows for page breaks.

Comment: then your enumerate is inside a `minipage` `parbox` or something similiar

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.